# Firebird 2.5 Database Corrupt

Tags: database, firebird, corruption

We have an issue where a database hangs the server when:

- a backup is performed (Hangs on a specific table)
- selecting * or count(1) from a specific table
- or viewing data that is related to the table (FKs, etc)

We could browse the table to a certain point (using IBExpert) however after about 2900 records the machine just spikes and hangs.

Performing a `gfix -m` does not work, and the validation reports back `Record level errors = 4` (no matter how many times we run `gfix -m`, `-v`, etc.

The `Firebird.log` file reports back these types of messages:

- Relation has 91631 orphan backversions (9214273 in use) in table BINS (137) - {Which is apparently just a warning}
- Unable to complete network request to host "MHPLZA1".
   Error reading data from the connection.
- INET/inet_error: read errno = 10054
- SERVER/process_packet: broken port, server exiting
- Shutting down the server with 1 active connection(s) to 1 database(s), 0 active service(s) - {If we leave the backup to run while hanging, it eventually logs this error message}

The setup is:

- The table is question has about 7000 records.
- The Firebird version is 2.5 Classic Server x64 install.
- The OS is Windows Server 2008.
- This is a virtual machine (VMWare) running on a massive server. (Does anyone have issues with VMs and Firebird?).

We have the same setup running fine on other servers (However they are not virtual machines).

Is there anyway to pin point the issue and or the cause?

Comment: No problem with WMWare and Firebird for me